# Change Subject and Content of WordPress Default Activation Email

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, function

When a user registers on my site, they receive an email to activate their account, but this email is in english and I need to change its content.

I've tried changing the default WordPress language but the emails still go out in english.

How can I achieve this? Can I do it by adding some code on my functions.php?

This is the email that I'm talking about,

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: http://aaronjerad.com/blog/change-default-wordpress-account-activation-email-subject-message-sender/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using BuddyPress, all of the email templates can be customized in the Admin Dashboard by clicking Emails->All Emails or Emails->Customize.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any of the following method

First thing you need to do is install and activate SB Welcome Email Editor plugin. After activating the plugin, go to Settings » SB Welcome Email to create your custom email messages.

[first method](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15304/how-to-change-the-default-registration-email-plugin-and-or-non-plugin)
or

the new user email is sent using wp_new_user_notification() function which is pluggable meaning that you can overwrite it:

[second method](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15304/how-to-change-the-default-registration-email-plugin-and-or-non-plugin)